# net50 Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) is returning an empty string on MacOS?

Tags: macos, environment-variables, .net-5, application-data

We need a path like `/Users/$usr/Library/Preferences` or `/Users/$usr/.config` to put our app data in it, how can we get it?

Unfortunatly

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

is returning an empty string on a non-developer Mac machine with OSX Mojave 10.14.6 on which **net50 runtime** and **net50 SDK** are installed. What is the best option to obtain reliably such folder on all Mac machines?